# question about a complex manifold

Tags: complex-analysis, several-complex-variables

Is the subspace of $\mathbb C^2$ of those vectors with real coordinates a complex submanifold?

Comment: Perhaps part of the issue here is that, as a topological space, your subspace is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{C}$ and can thus certainly be endowed with the structure of a complex manifold.  But being a complex *sub*manifold of $\mathbb{C}^2$ is a stronger condition, as Mariano's response addresses.

Comment: Thanks Pete.  I see know how my thinking was wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call that subspace $X$. Then the composition of the inclusion $X\to \mathbb C^2$ with the first projection $\mathbb C^2\to\mathbb C$ is an holomorphic map defined on a $1$-dimensional complex manifold which takes only real values. Such a function is necessarily constant. Now do the same for the second projection. What can you conclude?

Comment: It makes for a fun exercise to determine the $\mathbb R$-lineal subspaces of dimension $2$ in $\mathbb C^2$ which are complex submanifolds.

Comment: Ah, thanks!  I see now.